# Python with BS4 and urllib - How to move/manipulate text once extracted from a website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

Looking to write a program to look up NBA Win/Loss stats for any given team - and then return the numbers(i.e (3/6, 50%"))

A better way to understand...
Run the code ---- select Lakers ---- returns stats based on the next game ---- return percentages for home record after away win, after away loss, after home win, after home loss
and same 4 for an away game

My thoughts for it - 
Find a way to iterate through the text and select or extract the elements that I want and then run some simple numbers based off those... or again iterate through each game and keep a tally on each of the percentages I would like returned -- so maybe set each of those 4 stats I would like to a variable, tally or add to them when iterating through list of games and then return the results

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request


sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.espn.com/nba/team/schedule/_/name/lal').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table')
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)
```

This code will return a big set of all the data I want

```
['Fri, Dec 21', 'vs New Orleans ', 'W112-104  ', '19-13', 'Kuzma  23', 'James  12', 'James  14']
['Sun, Dec 23', 'vs Memphis ', 'L107-99  ', '19-14', 'James  22', 'James  14', 'James  7']
['Tue, Dec 25', '@ Golden State ', 'W127-101  ', '20-14', 'Kuzma  19', 'James  13', 'Rondo  10']
['Thu, Dec 27', '@ Sacramento ', 'L117-116  ', '20-15', 'Kuzma  33', 'Chandler  10', 'Ball  12']
['Date', 'Opponent', 'Time', 'TV', 'tickets']
['Fri, Dec 28', 'vs LA ', '10:30 PM ', 'NBATV', '1,143 tickets as low as $175 ']
['Sun, Dec 30', 'vs Sacramento ', '9:30 PM ', '', '1,270 tickets as low as $136 ']
['Wed, Jan 2', 'vs Oklahoma City ', '10:30 PM ', '', '1,240 tickets as low as $175 ']
```

I am looking to of course complete my code but for now am looking for a little help on messing around with the data. I am most curious on how to just say ----- create a new list with all of the '@' away games in it and a list with all of the home games in it with BS4 and url lib as I
am basically a complete beginner in both.

I have tried a few things like messing around with the row = [i.text for in in td] and tried to extract string, text, but just can't find the right thing, some of it is incorrect syntax and I think some is just not having the right code. Any help is appreciated!

From there I can work on figuring out the other code that would be needed to do the actual calculations as stated at the start and if needed any other help I can repost or ask another question!

Comment: A quick recommendation, you may want to store the information in something else, like a pandas dataframe. Then you can manipulate the data how you would like.

Comment: I agree that using pandas to put into a dataframe could make things easier for you. I’d also maybe look at using ‘pd.read_html(url)’, as that May do most of the work for you since it’s tagged as ‘table’

Comment: I should clarify when I say, “do most of the work”, as it’ll put it in a nice dataframe for you. You’d still need to go back and group, aggregate, manipulate, the data to get the calculations you’re looking for.

Comment: Thanks guys, I am currently looking into Pandas, just got it installed so going to mess around with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will get you going.

```
import pandas as pd

url = "http://www.espn.com/nba/team/schedule/_/name/lal"

# get all tables in url
dfs = pd.read_html(url)

# there were 3 tables. We want table in index position 2
df = dfs[2]

# take the first row (index 0) and make that the column names. Drop that first row and re index the dataframe
df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0]).reset_index(drop = True)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
           Date         Opponent       ...          Hi Rebounds       Hi Assists
0   Thu, Oct 18       @ Portland       ...             James 12         Rondo 11
1   Sat, Oct 20       vs Houston       ...              Rondo 7         Rondo 10
2   Mon, Oct 22   vs San Antonio       ...              Hart 10         James 14
3   Wed, Oct 24        @ Phoenix       ...         Stephenson 8         James 10
4   Thu, Oct 25        vs Denver       ...             James 11         James 11
5   Sat, Oct 27    @ San Antonio       ...             James 11          Rondo 5
6   Mon, Oct 29      @ Minnesota       ...             James 10          James 8
7   Wed, Oct 31        vs Dallas       ...             McGee 15           Ball 7
8    Sat, Nov 3       @ Portland       ...             Rondo 10          James 7
9    Sun, Nov 4       vs Toronto       ...               Ball 9          James 6
10   Wed, Nov 7     vs Minnesota       ...             James 11         Rondo 10
11  Sat, Nov 10     @ Sacramento       ...          Chandler 12          Rondo 7
```

Once you have that dataframe, start filtering rows, or spliting rows with the "@". Do some groupby to group away games/home games. You can start parsing date column too. Lots of stuff you can play around with the data with pandas.

Comment: Awesome, this is perfect!

Comment: What I would do next now that you have the data frame is to probably delimit the opponent column by space which will give you a column of just @ and vs and another column with just the opponent. Then you can change the @'s to Away and the vs's to Home, and see the home/away winning percentages etc.

Comment: @AustinKluver, bbd108 has the right idea. It’s probably what I would have done next. Work on separating the 1 opponents column into 2 columns of @/vs and opponents. then replace with @/vs with ‘Away’/‘Home’. Then you can work on the date column to turn that into datetime type. Then you can create a “days rest” column that calculates how many days rest between games using that date column. See winning percentage on back-to-back games, 1 day rest, 2 days rest, etc. Like I said, tons of good practice and fun things you can do with this dataframe.

Comment: Id probably also delimit the score column at ‘-‘ and you can start doing averages on pts scored, pts allowed in those same situations. Although it’s a little trickier with ‘W’ and ‘L’ and since that determines if it’s the relevant teams points 1st or 2nd, so that would be another thing that you’d have to work out. But then you can ask questions Like what’s their average pts for packers in home games following away, or vice versa.